# Sum limit. Please tell if correct.

Tags: limits, summation

I just solved this limit, and the result provided by the book is different.

$$ \lim_{x\to 1} \frac{x+x^2+x^3 + ... + x^n - n}{x-1} $$
I turned this into:
$$ \lim_{x\to 1} \frac{x-1}{x-1} + \frac{x^2-1}{x-1} + \frac{x^3-1}{x-1} + ...  + \frac{x^n-1}{x-1} $$
$$ \lim_{x\to 1} 1 + x + (x + x^2) + (x + x^2 + x^3) +...+(x + x^2 + ... +         x^{n-1})$$
$$ 1 + 1 + 2 +3 +...+ n-1 $$
My result: $ \frac{n(n-1)}{2}+1 $

Books result: $ \frac{n(n-1)}{2} $

Have i missed something?

Comment: Curious. My answer is n(n+1)/2 (You have forget the 1 in each of the terms of your sum unless the first one so you should have 1+2+....+n)

Comment: Your method is slick (and I like it).  To verify, this is a good candidate for L'Hopital's rule.  If you use it, the limit comes out to $1 + 2 + 3 + ... + n = \binom{n+1}{2}$.

Answer (score 0):

Your method of solving is correct and nice, but there are some mistakes. First

$$\frac{x^k-1}{x-1}=x^{k-1}+x^{k-2}+\ldots+x+1$$

and thus

$$\frac{x+x^2+\ldots+x^n-n}{x-1}=\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{x^k-1}{x-1}=$$

$$=\sum_{k=1}^n\left(1+x+\ldots+x^{k-1}\right)=1+2+\ldots+n=\frac{n(n+1)}2$$

One can also do the following, though perhaps you haven't yet studied this: define

$$f(x)=x+x^2+\ldots+x^n\;,\;\;n\in\Bbb N\;\;\text{a constant}$$

Then your limit is this functions' derivative at $\;x=1\;$ :

$$\lim_{x\to1}\frac{x+x^2+\ldots+x^n-n}{x-1}=\lim_{x\to 1}\frac{f(x)-f(1)}{x-1}=f'(1)$$

and since $\;f'(x)=1+2x+3x^2+\ldots+nx^{n-1}\;$ , we get that

$$f'(1)=1+2+3+\ldots+n=\frac{n(n+1)}2$$